# http://localhost:6000/__swagger__/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. Plumber swagger-UI not working

Tags: r, swagger, rstudio, plumber

In RStudio when I try to run a plumber server with a specific port number, the swagger-UI is not working. If I run the server without specifying the port it will work fine. 
Notice that the API is working, is just the swagger-UI that is missing.

How can I fix this?
Also, there is a way to get to see the swagger file?

Here is the R and RStudio versions:

RStudio v1.2.1335
Build 1379 (f1ac3452)

This is the output of the 'version' command:

```
>version

platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.0                         
year           2019                        
month          04                          
day            26                          
svn rev        76424
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
nickname       Planting of a Tree
```

Passing this code swagger-UI works:

```
# my-script.R
library(plumber)
r <- plumber::plumb("server.R")
r$run()
```

Result:

> Starting server to listen on port 5418
>   Running the swagger-UI at [http://127.0.0.1:5418/**swagger**/](http://127.0.0.1:5418/__swagger__/)
>   [Swagger-UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3BFK.jpg)

Passing a specific port number it won't work:

```
r$run(port = 6000)
```

Result:

> Starting server to listen on port 6000
>   Running the swagger UI at [http://127.0.0.1:6000/**swagger**/](http://127.0.0.1:6000/__swagger__/)
>   [Swagger-UI not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq9ei.jpg)

Api working but swagger-UI not available even if the output shows otherwise.
Thanks in advance for your help.